# Solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^3(e^{1/x} - 1)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Solve that the following integral
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^3(e^{1/x} - 1)}. $$
I just know this is $\pi^2/6$. I think it's related to $\zeta(2)$, but I cannot figure this integral out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub $x=1/u$, $dx = -du/u^2$ to get

$$\int_0^{\infty}du \frac{u}{e^u-1} = \int_0^{\infty} du \frac{u \, e^{-u}}{1-e^{-u}}$$

Taylor expand the denominator, switch order of summation and integration:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} du \, u \, e^{-(k+1) u} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(k+1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$